# EF6 MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer stuck after Update-database

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've created a project using EF code first but am stuck with the application unable to initialize (unless I enable automatic migrations which I don't want). This isn't a production system, but I'm trying to learn how to use code-first (and am struggling).

I've previously been through the steps to enable code first migrations, I have a configuration class with a seed method, and my project has worked previously.

I started getting an error:

> "Unable to update database to match the current model because there
>   are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled"

So I've done the following:

- Dropped the database completely, and created an empty one.
- Deleted all existing DbMigration classes in the project
- Created a new DbMigration class called 'InitialState' with the 'add-migration' command.
- Run the 'update-database' command

The database update runs successfully, the seed method runs successfully and I can see the tables and data in my database. There is one row in the migration history table for my one migration 'InitialState'. It all looks fine, but when I run up the application, still get the same initial error. If I run the 'add-migration' and 'update-database' commands again, it creates a blank migration and updates, but I still get the error.

If I enable automatic migrations, an auto-migration entry appears in the migrations table and my app runs. But I don't want automatic migrations.

Comment: Let it auto update the database but have a sql profiler active in the background and see what actual tables/columns are updated during the auto migration. This should give you enough clues on what happens.